# Knuth's Word Wrap Algorithm in Haskell

Tags: performance, algorithm, strings, haskell

I put together a Haskell function for [Knuth's word wrap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Knuth.27s_algorithm). A simplified version of the algorithm is described [here](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs1141/www/assignments/prog2.pdf).

I've already been told that there are certain aspects of my style that are not very agreeable (e.g. lack of comments and type declarations). However, I'd like to get some opinions on where I might be able to improve the performance of the code itself without resorting to agressive, structure breaking optimization techniques.

```
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

knuth m xs = map (concat . intersperse " ") $ split ixs 1 ws
  where
    (_:ixs)           = reverse $ snd (c ! lls)
    ws                = words xs
    ls                = map length ws
    lls               = length ls

    split [] _ ws     = [ws]
    split (x:xs) n ws = let (a, b) = splitAt (x-n) ws in a : split xs x b

    c                 = listArray (0, lls) $ map go [0..lls]
      where
        go 0          = (0, [])
        go j          = minimumBy (comparing fst) $ map (path j) [1..j]
        path j i      = let (x, p) = c ! (i-1) in (lc ! (i, j) + x, i:p)

    lc                = listArray ((1, 1), (lls, lls)) $ concat $ go ls
      where
        go            = map (costs . extras) . take lls . tails
        extras        = lpad lls 0 . map (m -) . zipWith (+) [0..] . scanl1 (+)
        lpad m x      = reverse . take m . (++ repeat x) . reverse
        costs []      = []
        costs (e:es)
          | e < 0     = (1/0) : costs es
          | null es   = [0]
          | otherwise = exp (fromIntegral e) : costs es
```

The code can be exercised like the following examples:

```
t1 = knuth 6 "aaa bb cc ddddd"
t2 = knuth 37 "You cant trust code that you did not create yourself. (Especially code from companies that employ people like me.) No amount of source-level verification or scrutiny will protect you from untrusted code."
```

Comment: Is there a link to Knuth's algorithm with actual code or pseudo code? Preferably the one you used. (Or can you quote the code here?)

Comment: Sure. http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs1141/www/assignments/prog2.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Lack of comments, type information, and good naming makes this code much harder to read than it should be.

`lls` is not descriptive, and the s at the end makes it sound like a list of something, when it's just a number.  Since `n` is not used for anything else, I'd go with that.

The names `c` and `lc` are horrible, these arrays are central to the algorithm, and their definitions take up most of the function, but there is nothing to tell us what they are in the program.  The linked article says that the `c` array represents cumulative costs, and `lc[i][j]` is the cost of a line containing words i through j, so I would suggest the names `cumulativeCost` and `lineCost`.  However, the `c` in your program also adds the `p` array from the article, so `cumulativeCost` doesn't quite cover it.  `cumulativeCostAndPath` is a bit long, but not too bad.

Since we're only ever interested in either the cost or the path from `cumulativeCostAndPath` (though they're calculated together), I'd suggest `getpath = snd` and `cumCost = fst` as ways of being clearer about what you mean (you could also separate the pieces, but that would be more work).

With these name changes, the first confusing line of the program, `(_:ixs) = reverse $ snd (c ! lls)` becomes `(_:ixs) = reverse $ getpath (cumulativeCostAndPath ! n)`.

`path j i = let (x, p) = c ! (i-1) in (lc ! (i, j) + x, i:p)` is also hard to read, mostly because of naming.  It uses 6 names, of which `lc` is the only one with more than one character, and only `i` and `j` have obvious meanings.  I'm going to call `x` `costSoFar` and `p` `pathSoFar`.  I'm also going to change the `let` into a `where` and break it into 2 lines.

```
path j i = (lineCost ! (i, j) + costSoFar, i:pathSoFar)
           where (costSoFar, pathSoFar) = cumulativeCostAndPath ! (i-1)
```

It is not obvious what `extras` is trying to do, even with the article as a reference.  It would be much easier to follow with a comment explaining the formula for `extras[i][j]` in the article, what extras is meant to represent, and mentioning that the `scanl1` call in `extras` and the `tails` call in `go` interact to create the last term in extras.

The `costs` function could use a comment explaining what each of the 3 possibilities means.  If `extras` were extracted to be its own array, it would allow `costs` to be rewritten more cleanly, as well as potentially simplifying the definition of `lc`.  Before figuring out the details of what's going on, that deep pipeline of functions was hard to reason about.

You spend a lot of effort making lists which have to match up to arrays.  This is harder to follow than defining each array element with a function (which is possible for these arrays), and it sets you up for off-by-one errors if you're not careful.

I can see two possible ways to speed it up.  You use `exp` in the definition of `costs`, which is more expensive than the 2 multiplications required for cubing suggested in the article.  Also, the calculation of `extras` doesn't stop after it's impossible.  Since after finding that words i through j won't fit, all of the rest of them won't fit either, you could avoid calculating everything after the first negative number.  If you have 500 words to wrap and an 80 column limit, figuring out whether you can fit words 1 through 200 on a line is a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I agree with @MichaelShaw on most points. So I won't repeat the "use meaningful names and types" part, as he covered it well enough. I will also touch upon the problem I see with nesting; and on readability, I will second his comment

> You spend a lot of effort making lists which have to match up to
>   arrays. This is harder to follow than defining each array element with
>   a function

with actual examples and with special emphasis on using the same language as your requirements (within technical limitations).

### Too much nesting

There is too much nesting in the code. Any function doing anything of interest should be top level. So it could be tested individually or developed in the REPL etc, but functions defined in `where` clauses cannot be tested.

If you're doing this because you want to expost `knuth` function only, put your functions in a module and export only the functions you want to expose. Something like this : `module Homework2 ( knuth ) where`.

And If you're doing this because you want to close over fixed inputs such as `m`, just don't. If you use consistent and/or meaningful names for common parameters then it won't be a problem.

For example in the homework you are given:

```
extras i j = {- expression containing m l in addition to i j -}
```

can be expressed as

```
extras :: {- after you develop your function in REPL; 
             copy, fix if too general, and paste the type signature REPL gives -}
extras m l = extras' where extras' i j = ...
```

or

```
(extras m l) i j = ...
```

### Opaqueness

Another problem with the code is its opaqueness. Your code should speak the language of your requirements

$$extras[i][j] = M - j + i - \sum_{k=i}^{j} l_k$$

Compare:

```
extra m l i j = m - j + i + sumLk
  where 
    sumLk = sum [l!k | k <- [i .. j]]
```

With:

```
extras = lpad lls 0 . map (m -) . zipWith (+) [0..] . scanl1 (+)
  where
    lpad m x = reverse . take m . (++ repeat x) . reverse
```

$$
 lc[i][j] =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill \infty    \hfill & \text{ if $extras[i][j]<0$} \\
      \hfill 0    \hfill & \text{ if $j=n$ and is even $extras[i][j] \geq 0$} \\
      \hfill (extras[i][j])^3 \hfill & \text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Compare:

```
cost m n l = lc 
  where
    lc i j 
      | extra' < 0 = 1/0
      | j == n     = 0
      | otherwise  = fromIntegral $ extra' ^ 3
        where
          extra' = extra m l i j
```

With:

```
costs []      = []
costs (e:es)
  | e < 0     = (1/0) : costs es
  | null es   = [0]
  | otherwise = exp (fromIntegral e) : costs es
```

The problem with the naive implementation `cost` is that it takes \$O(n^3)\$ to fill its results in an array. But it can be optimized back to \$O(n^2)\$

```
lc m n ls = array ((1,1),(n,n)) [ ((i, j), cost' i j) 
  | i <- [1..n], j <- [1..n], i < j]
  where
    r = runningTotals n ls
    cost' = cost m n r

cost :: Int -> Int -> Array Int Int -> (Int -> Int -> Float)
cost m n r i j 
  | extra < 0 = 1/0
  | j == n = 0
  | otherwise = fromIntegral $ extra ^ 3
  where
    extra = m - j + i + sumLk
    sumLk = r!j - r!(i-1)

runningTotals :: (Num a) => Int -> [a] -> Array Int a 
runningTotals n = listArray (0,n) . scanl (+) 0
```

Also not I added `i < j` in the definition of `lc`, even it wouldn't give any performance benefits, but now I can be sure I will not be iterating on the cases (i>j), for which cost is trivially infinity, when defining `c`. Also I am now sure I won't be accessing `lc!(j,i)` instead of `lc!(i,j)`, or similar typo or off-by-one errors.

$$
 c[j] =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill 0    \hfill & j = 0 \\
      \hfill \min_{1 \leq i \leq j} (c[i-1]+lc[i][ j]) \hfill & j>0 \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Naive implementation:

```
cumulativeCost m n l = c
  where
    c 0 = 0
    c j = minimum [c (i-1) + lc i j | i <- [1 .. j]]
    lc = cost m n l
```

Memoized implementation:

```
c m n ls = c'
  where
    c' = array (0,n) [(i, c'' i) | i <- [0..n]]
    c'' 0 = 0
    c'' j = minimum [(c'!i-1) + (lc'!(i,j)) | i <- [1 .. j]]
    lc' = lc m ls
```

The definition of `c` is not compared to yours because the one above doesn't contain path building code.

### Some further refactorings:

Above `c` is dependent on the particular `lc` and above `lc` is dependent on the particular `cost` function only by accident; you can pass `lc` and `cost` in as parameters respectively... (The same is true for your `knuth` function: You shouldn't need to recompile it in order to use `exp extra` instead of `extra^3` as cost. Also you should be able to run `knuth` with different cost functions and compare the results.)

As for performance, you can do some cut off in the calculation of `c[j]`. I think this is also the improvements suggested by @MichaelShaw. But his wording

> Since after finding that words i through j won't fit, all of the rest
>   of them won't fit either,

suggests, even if it may not be what he means, "f i..j doesn't fit i..j+1 won't fit either", but that requires using mutable arrays I guess. Instead you should think "If i..j doesn't fit i-1..j won't fit either". And that means you should iterate `i`s in decreasing order.

```
-- instead of this
c'' j = minimum [(c'!i-1) + (lc!(i,j)) | i <- [1 .. j]]
-- this
c'' j = minimum $ takeWhile (< 1/0) [(c'!i-1) + (lc!(i,j)) | i <- [j,j-1..1]]
```

This can be a very significant improvement for large n. If your function will be run against huge inputs (as is case with programming competitions). However IRL you word-wrap one paragraph at a time, where n~50. Another concern is now your implementation would be tied to this particular cost function again. Although it is safe to assume costs will never be more than `(1/0)`, cost function shouldn't use `Infinity` to disallow any other kind of line break. You should put your assumption `lc[i][j] == Infinity => lc[i-1][j] == Infinity` in the documentation for `c` (which is another sign that `c` should take `lc` as a parameter).

Another cut-off strategy that can improve performance could be `takeWhile (j - i < maxWordsPerLine)`. `maxWordsPerLine = 1 + lineWidth/spaceWidth` could be a safe bet. This strategy would decrease time complexity significantly for n >> maxWordsPerLine, from O(n^2) to O(n*maxWordsPerLine); though which is never the case IRL either. Of course, if your program would be run against n >> maxWordsPerLine, nXn monolithic array would not be the best data structure.

Comment: +1.  What I meant by that wording was "if i..j doesn't fit then i..j+1 won't either", but your way of looking at it is also true.  Both are adding words to a line that's already too long.  I was thinking in terms of generating `extras` a line at a time (with a fixed `i` for a given line).  Your point that it would also save time in generating `c` is a good one, and for that, since we're interested in `c[j]`, fixing `j` makes sense.